# Game Center achievement banners not displaying on unlock (Unity)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, notifications, game-center, achievements

My app (iOS) uses Game Center for its leaderboard functionality as well as its achievement system. I am using the built in libraries for Game Center integration for unity. My achievements work as intended, however when a user unlocks an achievement, there is no notification banner to indicate that the user has unlocked it. Naturally I have

```
GameCenterPlatform.ShowDefaultAchievementCompletionBanner(true);
```

with the header using

```
UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.GameCenter;
```

and the standard authentication script before performing any actions, but despite my greatest efforts, the live version of the app does not display banner notifications upon unlocking an achievement. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like such an idiot, but the solution was quite simple. Download the [GKAchievementReporter.unitypackage](https://forum.unity.com/attachments/gkachievementreporter-unitypackage.143908/) and import it in to your project. Replace your Social.ReportProgress() method with

```
GKAchievementReporter.ReportAchievement(achievementID, progress, showsCompletionBanner);
```

Comment: For some reason, I arrived here by upgrading an old iOS project and my solution was to get rid of `GKAchievementReporter` plugin and revert back to the original `social.ReportProgress` as documented here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.ReportProgress.html Hopefully, achievements got fixed after Unity 5.6. I did not confirm the banners show yet tho